# Error migrating my testing databases

Tags: php, database, testing, command-line, migration

This is the error I keep getting:

```
➜  desk git:(message) ✗ php artisan migrate --env="testing"

[InvalidArgumentException]
Database does not exist.
```

I am not sure how to fix this?

Comment: We're not either. Not without some extra work from you

Comment: I am sorry Daryl what does that mean?

Comment: Is this the code you are piping to the command console?

Comment: And what have you done to try to fix it yourself?

Comment: As: http://laravel.com/docs/artisan has slight differences between exampled/working to yours

Comment: I tried both and they both produce the same error.